# When are the best times/months to catch speckled trout on the US Gulf Coast?

Tags: fishing, united-states-gulf-coast

I would like to go fishing for [speckled trout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynoscion_nebulosus) (proper name spotted seatrout) along the US Gulf Coast, specifically near Galveston Bay and Trinity Bay.

What months are the best times to catch speckled trout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texas has a coast-wide, year-round speckled trout fishery. But Speckled trout fishing is hot in May and June and from October through January.